# SQL Not Querying JSON Data That Happens to Contain ':null'

Tags: python, sql, json, postgresql, sqlite

I am trying to do insert and select SQL queries within my flask web app's main python file. I am using SQLAlchemy and sqlite3 on the development version (and postgresql on the server version) and they all led to the same problem when trying to query JSON data that happens to contain ':null'. You can see the SQL query used as well as the error in more detail in the following pictures where it says:

```
"expirationTime":null
```

[Picture of the error, in dev environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPoUw.png)

Is there anyway to make SQL accept the JSON data without having to modify the JSON data itself?

Ideally I would be able to INSERT the JSON data into a column and/or use SELECT to compare it against other JSON data. Thank you.

Comment: This is not an SQL error.  It appears to be Alchemy error, but you have not shown the code that generates it.  It looks like you doing an accidental SQL injection.

Comment: @jjanes If I replace the `null` in the JSON with ` null` (with a space in front) then it works.

Comment: I was basically doing `INSERT INTO subs (user_id, subscription_json) VALUES (session["user_id"], jsonData)` where jsonData is a stringified JSON being inserted into a text column.

Comment: You should be binding the parameter correctly, not directly interpolating it into the query string.  Then it won't interpret `:null` as the name of another bind variable.